# CSS webdesign footer positioning

Tags: html, css

There is a problem with styling footer and with class "sloupec1" and "sloupec2"please help me.

```
<footer>
    <div class="sloupec1">
        <h3>VŠE O NÁKUPU</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Obchodní podmínky</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Možnosti doručení</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Možnosti platby</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sloupec2">
        <h3>O SPOLEČNOSTI</h3>
        <p>Základní informace</p>
        <p>Kontakt</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="copyright">
        &copy; 2023 Mojezahrada.cz Všechna práva vyhrazena.
    </div>
</footer>
```

I need to style 2 columns adjacent, tried float but it don't work. So I ask AI it only tell me something with flexbox, but it don't work well. I need to get really similar footer like this:

Web design:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1083872226476032121/1083873552274554920/tohle_je_navrh_webu_upraveno.png
all code (html+css) without images:
https://pastebin.com/KSfguz0j

Next problem is I need to make this website responsive.

Comment: Can you please use StackOverflow's HTML, CSS, and Javascript snippet to post your code,
also please just post the part that's causing the problem and not the entire code, since you're having issues with placing div's adjacent to each other you should only post that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `display: flex;` to place 2 divs adjacent to each other

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div>Column 1</div>
  <div>Column 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it will work.

In this code, I added a div and applied flex display to it and by default the justify-content value is flex-start so just add auto margins to the 2nd div and it will be centered in the only available empty space.

```css
.sloupecs-container {
  display: flex;
}

.sloupec2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="sloupecs-container"> 
    <div class="sloupec1">
        <h3>VŠE O NÁKUPU</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Obchodní podmínky</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Možnosti doručení</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Možnosti platby</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="sloupec2">
        <h3>O SPOLEČNOSTI</h3>
        <p>Základní informace</p>
        <p>Kontakt</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="copyright">
      &copy; 2023 Mojezahrada.cz Všechna práva vyhrazena.
  </div>
</footer>
```